# SQL Server 2005 and temporary table scope

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've read around the subject of temporary tables and scope and all the answers i've seen don't seem to talk about one of my concerns.

I understand that a local temporary table's scope is only valid withing the lifetime of a stored procedure or child stored procedures. However what is the situation with regard to concurency. i.e. if i have a stored procedure that creates a temporary table which is called from two different processes but from the same user/connection string, will that temporary table be shared between the two calls to that one stored procedure or will it be a case of each call to the stored procedure creates an unique temporary table instance.

I would assume that the temporary table belongs to the scope of the call to the stored procdure but i want to be sure before i go down a path with this.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Local temporary tables (start with #) are limited to your session; other sessions, even from the same user/connection string, can't see them.  The rules for the lifetime depend on whether the local temporary table was created in a stored procedure:

- A local temporary table that is created in a stored procedure is dropped when the procedure ends; other stored procedures, or the calling process, can't see them.
- Other local temporary tables are dropped when the session ends.

Global temporary tables (start with ##) are shared between sessions.  They are dropped when:

- The session that created them ends
- AND no other session is referring to them

This command can be handy to see which temporary tables exist:

```
select TABLE_NAME from tempdb.information_schema.tables
```

And this is handy to drop temporary tables if you're not sure they exist:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#SoTest') is not null drop table #SoTest
```

See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258255(SQL.80).aspx) for more information.

Comment: +1 This is an awesome answer. Can you please confirm this? If a stored procedure is being executed multiple times from the same connection string, the latter statement `if object_id...` determines the existence of a temporary table in the session from which it is being called. Is my understanding correct? I understand that sessions won't know the existence of temp tables but I'm just wondering if the `object_id` returns the value based on a session.

Comment: @Legend: `object_id` should only see temporary tables from your own session.  Should be easy to test.

Comment: +1 Yes just checked it myself too. Really appreciate your response. Thank you.

Comment: Someone's stealing your thunder :) https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/522d302a-857f-4730-b49f-cca7fb236912/is-it-necessary-to-clean-up-drop-temporary-tables-in-stored-procedures?forum=transactsql

Answer (score 11):

The temporary table will be accesible to the instance of the procedure that creates it

The following script

```
Exec ('Select 1 as col Into #Temp Select * From #Temp')
Exec ('Select 2 as col Into #Temp Select * From #Temp')
```

Returns

```
Col
1

Col
2
```

Not

```
Col
1
2
```

Or an error because the table already exists.

The temporary table will also be accesible by any 'child' procedures that the initial procedure runs as well.

Comment: +1 Good point, Exec() starts an inner scope. Temporary tables created inside exec() are not visible to the parent.  The parent's temporary tables are visible to the child, but if the child creates a temporary table with the same name, it will create a new table.

Answer (score 2):

You might also think about using table variables.  They have a very well-defined scope, and they are sometimes faster than their temporary table counterparts.  The only problem with table variables is that they cannot be indexed, so some performance could be lost despite their nature.  [Check here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175774(SQL.80).aspx) for some more information on the subject.

Comment: The big difference between table variables and temporary tables is that you cannot ALTER TABLE a table variable. You can, however, ALTER TABLE a temporary table.

Comment: Table Variables are good, but usually if you're not going to store a lot of information in them. I generally try to use CTEs and when I can't, I'll use a temporary table with an index.