# Temp table variables doesn't seem to be working when SP is called from c#

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I am calling a stored procedure from C# code. This SP creates temp tables to store some values. When I run this SP from Query Analyzer everything seems to be fine. But when I run it from c# code, temp tables are not getting created.

I am using @tableName and not #tableName.

The temp tables are being referred only in stored procedure. They are not needed outside the SP.
[image]
Is there anything I am missing out ?

Comment: Yes - you're missing out posting some code!

Comment: It's the temp table scope: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/892351/sql-server-2005-and-temporary-table-scope

Comment: @ShellShock - Please find my recent edits.

Comment: How are you determining that those temp tables are not being created? what is the actual problem? are you not getting the expected results from the SP call?

Comment: Yes I am not getting desired results from the SP call. Sometimes it throws timeout expired error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because the user credentials you are using in Query analyzer ('sa' maybe?) are probably not the same than the ones used by the C# application.

The user needs to have access to system database tempdb (read/write) if not he cannot create those temporal tables (within the procedure) when the stored procedure is called.

Give access to tempdb to the user that C# uses or test your C# app login in with the same user you use in Query Analyzer (or any other dbadmin user) just to test it works.

As per your comment asking about SQL Profiler by statement.

Step 1: open sql profiler and create a new trace. go to tab event selection. and unmark Security Audit and Sessions

[image]

Step 2: check the Show all events checkbox on the bottom right and you will get several events on the grid. Go to Stored Procedures and T-SQL and mark the ones in the screenshot below.

[image]

Step 3: run it.

Comment: I am using same user sa for both Query analyzer as well as the application. :(

Comment: what is the error message being thrown by SQL? does it say that the temp table cannot be created? that it already exists?

Comment: It's not throwing any error, but keeps on running. Nothing is being logged in SQL profiler. I can see the call to SP, but no any other internal statements.

Comment: then, how do you know that the temp table is not being created? what you can do is to, for testing purposes only, alter your procedure and insert the content of the temp table into a physical table... call it from C# app and see if there is something on the physical table.

Comment: When I execute the code, in SQL profiler I can see the call to SP, but not the create table or insert statements used for temp tables.

Comment: that is normal. You didn't select T-SQL begin statement, end statement nor SP begin statement, end statement in SQL Profiler. Do that and you will see each statement executed within the SP (and even triggers, etc.)

Comment: How to do that ? Please help me.

Comment: I am using @tableName and not #tableName. Table variables. Sorry for terms misuse.

Answer (score 0):

Temp tables are removed automatically when the session ends, are you sure it's not just being deleted once the C# code finishes up? [Review the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) for more information.