# how to access the temporary table created inside stored procedure [vb6]

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, vb6

I have a `stored procedure` inside which I am creating a temporary table.
My `vb` code will execute this stored procedure.

Is it possible to access the data in the temp table in `vb6` after sp execution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a global scope temporary table (they start with `##` rather than `#`). These are shared between sessions. They go out of scope when the session that created them ends AND no other session is referring to them.

- [Temporary Tables in SQL Server](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporary-tables-in-sql-server/)
- [Creating and Modifying Table Basics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177399%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx)
- [SQL Server 2005 and temporary table scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892351/sql-server-2005-and-temporary-table-scope)

Another option is a persistent temporary table (prefixed by `TempDB..`)

Answer (score 0):

From [Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx):

> A local temporary table created in a stored procedure is dropped
>   automatically when the stored procedure is finished. The table can be
>   referenced by any nested stored procedures executed by the stored
>   procedure that created the table. The table cannot be referenced by
>   the process that called the stored procedure that created the table.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary table created within a Stored Procedure is dropped when the Stored Procedure ends, so the answer is no.

If you really want to share a temporary table with the caller, you could do something like the following:

1. Conditionally create the temporary table in your Stored Procedure if it doesn't already exist

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure AS
       ...
       if object_id('tempdb..#temp') is null
       BEGIN
           CREATE TABLE #temp
           (...)
       END 
       ...
   ```
2. Whenever you want to access the temp table from your caller, you should create the temporary table before calling the stored procedure.

By creating the temporary table conditionally in the Stored Procedure, it will work whether or not the caller creates the temporary table.  The caller must of course create the temporary table with the correct structure, and DROP it when finished (or close the DB connection).

Answer (score 0):

An option I've used in the past is to create the temp table prior to calling the stored proc that uses it.  As long as you use the same open `adodb connection` it should work:

```
myAdoDBConn.Execute "CREATE TABLE #foo (ID integer)", , adCmdText
myADODBConn.Execute "StoredProcThatPopulatesFoo", , adCmdStoredProc

myAdoRecordset.Open "Select ID FROM #foo", myAdoDbConn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
Do While Not myAdoRecordset.EOF
  // do something with the record //
  myAdoRecordset.EOF
Loop
```

In this example, the temp table stays available until you close the connection (`myAdoDbConn`).

Comment: It works just fine unless you're doing it wrong.  And saying that isn't very conducive to conversation.  What exactly isn't working?  Are you getting an error?