# Lifespan of a Temp Table

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, temp-tables

I would like to ask as to what is the lifespan of a temp table created using windows app? I planned to segregate the creation of the temp table. But somewhere in this code segment, i am unable to get my selected table. Below is the code snippet to explain

```
Public Sub CreateTempTableWithData(ByVal tableName As String, ByVal connectionString As String, ByVal startDate As DateTime,
                                    ByVal endDate As DateTime, ByVal startSerialNo As String, ByVal endSerialNo As String,
                                    ByVal refTable As String, ByVal refKey As String, ByVal transferStatus As String)
    Dim dal As New DataTransferDal

    Dim tableSchemaList As New List(Of TableSchema)
    Dim sqlQuery As String
    Try
        ' 1. create temporary table
        sqlQuery = FormTempTable(tableName, connectionString, tableSchemaList)

        dal.ExecuteQuery(sqlQuery, connectionString)

        ' 2. populate temporary table
        sqlQuery = PopulateTempTable(tableName, refTable, startDate, endDate, startSerialNo, endSerialNo,
                                        refKey, tableSchemaList, transferStatus)
        ' Unable to retrieve my temp table
        dal.ExecuteQuery(sqlQuery, connectionString)     
    Catch dbEx As DbLoggingException
        ExceptionLogger.ErrorLogging(LoggingType.SQLException, dbEx)
    Catch ex As Exception
        ExceptionLogger.ErrorLogging(LoggingType.General, ex)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Is there any way to maintain my temporary table based on this sequence.

Comment: Instead of a temporary table, could you create an actual table that you then drop? SQL server temp tables are session scoped (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/892351/sql-server-2005-and-temporary-table-scope) and I'm unsure how the VB.net session handles sessions; you're depending on something that shouldn't really work that way.

Comment: It is impossible to create an actual table because the columns will differ. Which means, I would need to drop this temp table every time I'm finished creating it.

Comment: A temp table's scope is only the current session in which it is created, If your code is establishing two separate connections with database then temp tables created in one session will not be visible other sessions. In response to your statement " I would need to drop this temp table every time I'm finished" , the best practice is you drop temp tables too when you are done with them, because they will exist in the tempdb even though they have gone out of scope and only when sql server needs that space occupied by that temp table, it will drop them.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. But one inquiry: If the temp tables are still there even if there are two different sessions that created it, is there any way to access the one stored in the tempdb?

Comment: Yes; there are global temp tables, in SQL server these start with ## instead of # - they are out of scope when the last process finishes using them.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary table only exists within the session it was created. I noticed in the past that `ExecuteQuery` calls tend to run in their own sessions (try successive calls of `ExecuteQuery('SELECT @@SPID',connectionString)`). The table may still be there in `tempdb`, but other sessions are not allowed to access it.

For your case, it's better to join the creation and populate statements into a single `ExecuteQuery` call:

```
Try
    ' 1. create temporary table
    sqlQuery = FormTempTable(tableName, connectionString, tableSchemaList)

    ' 2. populate temporary table
    sqlQuery += ";" + PopulateTempTable(tableName, refTable, startDate, endDate, startSerialNo, endSerialNo,
                                    refKey, tableSchemaList, transferStatus)

    dal.ExecuteQuery(sqlQuery, connectionString)     
Catch dbEx As DbLoggingException
    ExceptionLogger.ErrorLogging(LoggingType.SQLException, dbEx)
Catch ex As Exception
    ExceptionLogger.ErrorLogging(LoggingType.General, ex)
End Try
```