# Temporary table not created from dynamic query execution

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If I run this dynamic query:

```
declare @test nvarchar(1000) = 'select * into #tmp7 from bauser'
execute(@test)
```

and then try to query `#tmp7` with:

```
select * from #tmp7
```

error is thrown:

> Invalid object name '#tmp7'.

However if I run the same query manually:

```
select * into #tmp7 from bauser
```

Everything is OK. Temporary table is created and filled with results.

Why is it not working with dynamic query execution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SCOPE!

The temporary table exists only in the scope of the dynamic executed query
If you do want to make the select put it inside the dynamic query

```
declare @test nvarchar(1000) = 'select * into #tmp7 from bauser

select * from #tmp7'
execute(@test)
```

Also you can check if a such object exists by using this

```
select * from sys.sysobjects so where so.name like '%tmp7%'
```

See this similar question
[SQL Server 2005 and temporary table scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892351/sql-server-2005-and-temporary-table-scope)

**Edit**

A temp table IS A TABLE so yes you can add columns, indexes, etc. Those tables resides in fact in the TempDB database and you can even "find" them (they can be seen with strange long names) but they are destroyed after the execution of your EXEC.

Maybe your problem is to try the dynamic approach or is not related to your question at all. Try to post a new question what you got and what you need to do to get further assistance.

Comment: Thanks for answer, yes scope is the problem. Is it possible somehow to later add some columns to #tmp?

Answer (score 1):

If you create temp table using dynamic SQL, it will not be available out of dynamic SQL scope.

You need to create it out of dynamic SQL and then use `INSERT INTO` to populate the table.

```
-- use this trick to create the temp table easily.
SELECT * INTO #tmp7
FROM bauser
WHERE 1=2

declare @test nvarchar(1000) = 'insert into #tmp7 select * from bauser'
execute(@test)
```

Comment: That's the problem - I have a lot of columns, created dynamically. I don't know which columns will be on the table before running time.

Comment: @FrenkyB If you really want to embark the pain train of dynamic queries you can make a query to create dynamic queries and maybe even create a dynamic query creates dynamic queries